# What is "excellense"?

Tags: orthography

A friend posted on Facebook showing a company (or maybe a school) notice which reads as "committed to excellense". Of course my friend is making fun of it, but I really doubt that there could be a reason to write "excellence" as "excellense". Can anybody explain this?

I also searched on Google, and there are multiple similar notices. One can see an example at [Pinterest](https://www.pinterest.com/pin/291959988314235622/).

Thank you.

Comment: Was it Flywheel, Shyster, and Flywheel; or St Trinian's?

Comment: You can see the image following this link: [link] https://www.pinterest.com/pin/291959988314235622/

Comment: You'd have to ask the people who made the sign. Most likely, they just don't know how to spell _excellence_, but it may also be a deliberate misspelling for whatever reason, like [this Australian church sign](https://melbournewelshchurch.wordpress.com/2013/05/08/we-strive-for-excellense/). That's not really about English as such, though. It's a misspelling, that's the only part that's about English—the rest is about the people/school/church/company who made the sign.

Comment: They managed to spell 'committed' correctly and put 'exc' instead of 'exs', so I wonder if it was deliberate?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about a simple typo.

Comment: It should be noted that it's possible to misspell "excellence" about 6 different ways.  It's fairly easy for a sign writer, being more concerned with forming & spacing the letters than double-checking the spelling, to make a mistake.  It happens with fair frequency.

Comment: I don't agree with the idea that a sign writer is more concerned with forming and spacing the letters. As Janus Bahs Jacquet commented above, it is possible that they did it deliberately, and I was wondering if the intention would be clear to someone native and aware of various cultures. I still think that there are enough number of searches on Google, and keeping the question could help many people what the rest of us think about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"[Whatever] to excellence" is a common tagline attached to company names or profiles. My guess is that in this case the author is using this misspelling for rhetorical (humorous) effect.

See: [catachresis](https://www.google.com/search?q=define%3Acatachresis&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8)